# Редирект 301 со слеша на без слеша

Tags: apache, редирект

При настройке 301 редиректа со слеша на без слеша, таким образом

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)(/)$ $1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

происходит перенаправление, но на несуществующую страницу.

Т.е. обращаясь к станице http://www.site.ru/catalog/   301-->   http://www.site.ru/django.wsgi/catalog (она 404).

То есть редирект отработал, слеша в конце url нет, но вопрос как убрать эту вложенность `django.wsgi`, чтобы было адекватный рабочий адрес http://www.site.ru/catalog (без слеша)

И во всей этой ситуации неприятно то, что все остальные страницы сайта отдают 404, кроме главной.

Comment: А покажите, что у вас в настройках апача прописано для WSGIScriptAlias? Да и вообще желательно увидеть весь VirtualHost :)

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса так как от автора не поступила затребованная необходимая информация.